# Show online/offline status of email address in Excel from MS Communicator

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, office-communicator-2007, status

I got a sheet of employees in Excel 2010 and would like to see who's online on Communicator jst by looking at the sheet and the row with employee's name. Each employee has the firm's email address in the sheet, of course.

How can I access this information from communicator from VBA/cell perspective?

Comment: Have you got smart tags turned on (under auto correction)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a VBA script (or .Net/any other language plugin) that uses the [Communicator Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758719%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It's probably one call per user ID.

Comment: do you have any example of usage? I can't see any relevant examples / resources for this MC communication across VBA in there. google didn't help a lot

Comment: I don't have specific sample code, but it shouldn't be different than other Office classes. If you do need a consultant to write the code for you (hint hint :) )

Comment: yeah, the project is my-position-need oriented. guys around here at company do not care about automation. Also a reason I'm quiting the company - dell. :)

Comment: Hah. Are you in Austin? These guys used to be my customers. Cool bunch. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The blog in this page explains how to get User status is Online or Offline in Office Communicator.

[Get User Status From Office Communicator](http://officetricks.com/find-availability-status-of-user-in-office-communicator-through-excel-vba-macro/)